# Pvlib get sun zenith angle

Tags: pvlib

does pvlib.location.Location.get_solarposition function returns the zenith angle in degrees or radians?
https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.location.Location.get_solarposition.html

Comment: Even if the documentation didn't specify, you could see for yourself: calculate hourly solar position across a day and look at what range the returned values span.  Examining the data yourself is a good habit to get into!

Answer (score 2):

While it isn't evident from the main wrapper function `get_solarposition`, if you look at the individual functions, e.g., https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/stable/generated/pvlib.solarposition.ephemeris.html, then you'll see it's in degrees.